# Bouncing ball bouncing off from another bal

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

I'm quite new to coding and so far I manage to make a program which is half way what I am asked to do. The task is to: Have a bouncing ball around the canvas and add a second, stationary ball in the centre of the canvas.  Have the bouncing ball bounce off of this.

My code is:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Javascript Game</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  
  
  <canvas 
   style="border:1px solid #000000;" 
   id = "mycanvas" 
   width = "500" 
   height = "500">
   
   Your browser does not support canvas
  </canvas>

  <script>
  
  window.addEventListener("load", myApp, false);


  function myApp() {
   var canvas;
   var context;
   var textToShow;
  
   function getCanvas() {
    var tmp;
    
    tmp = document.getElementById ("mycanvas");
    
    if (tmp == null) {
     alert ("no canvas");
    }
    
    return tmp;
     
   }

   function animateMe() {
   
    context.clearRect (0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
    context.stroke();
 
    x = x + xdir;
    //xdir = xdir +0.1;
    if (x + xdir == x2 -10){
    xdir *= -1;
    }else if (x + xdir>495) {
    xdir *=-1;
    }
    
    if (x+xdir <0){
    xdir *= -1;
    }
       
    y = y + ydir;
    if (y+ydir == y2- 10) {
    ydir += -1;
    }
    else if(y+ydir>=480){
    ydir *= -1;
    }
   
    if (y + ydir <0){
    ydir *= -1;
    }
    
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x2,y2,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
    context.stroke();

    requestAnimationFrame (animateMe);
   }

   canvas = getCanvas(); 
   context = canvas.getContext ("2d");
   
   init();
   
   function init() {
    x= 20;
    y=20;
    x2=250;
    y2=250;
    xdir= 5;
    ydir = 5;
    radius=10;
       
    animateMe();
   }   

  }
    
  </script>
  
 </body>
  
</html>
```

The thing is that the ball is bouncing off from the half of the screen and I have no idea how to make it go through that point, but bounce from the other ball at the same time.

Comment: You've coded it to work this way... `if (x + xdir == x2 -10) xdir *= -1;` changes the direction as soon as you reach the half-way mark of your canvas (canvas width is set to `500` and `x2` is set to half of that at `250`).

Answer (score 0):

```js
 myApp();


function myApp() {
  // No need for an init call at the moment.
  // init all stuff at start of this function
  var textToShow;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const w = canvas.width;
  const h = canvas.height;
  const  w2 = w / 2;
  const  h2 = h / 2;
  const  radius = 10;
  var  x = 20;
  var  y = 40;
  var  xdir = 5;
  var  ydir = 5;


       
  // use this to start rather than direct call.
  requestAnimationFrame(animateMe);


  function animateMe() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    
    // the best way to do the calulations is first move then draw
 
 

    x += xdir;
    y += ydir;

    const right = w - radius;
    const bottom = h - radius;
    
    // Test if the ball has gone to far and correct position and dir
    // As each frame is a descrete time step you need to acount for
    // the balls motion during the frame.
    
    // If the ball is past the edge then some time between the last 
    // this frame it hit the wall and started moving away from the wall
    // The distance moved away from the wall is the same as the distance 
    // we found the ball to far into the wall
    
    // If you do xdir *= -1; 
    // you dont know if the ball was  pushed there by something
    // (assuming you will have some form  of interaction) and was
    // unable to escape the wall the previouse frame. This can result in 
    // the ball sticking to the wall.
    // Always set the vector to the correct sign.
    
    
    if (x  > right) {
      x = right - (x - right);
      xdir = -Math.abs(xdir);
    } else if (x < radius) {
      x = radius + (radius - x);
      xdir = Math.abs(xdir);
    }
    if (y  > bottom) {
      y = bottom - (y - bottom);
      ydir = -Math.abs(ydir);
    } else if (y < radius) {
      y = radius + (radius - y);
      ydir = Math.abs(ydir);
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(w2, w2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    requestAnimationFrame(animateMe);
  }

}
```

```html
  <canvas style="border:1px solid #000000;" id="canvas" width="250" height="250">It's 2017 anyone that sees this message does not need to be told that nothing works.
  </canvas>
```